# PHP-GDS store string that is longer than 1500 bytes

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The PHP-GDS library is *awesome* - I can't stress that enough.

However there is a DataStore limitation that ->addString must contain a string that is less than 1500 bytes. Is there an alternative that will store strings that are greater than 1500 bytes? E.g. the DataStore documentation refers to a [TextProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#TextProperty%20type) type.

Would it be possible to add an ->addText() method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Datastore docs here:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Properties_and_value_types

If differentiates between 1500 or 1MB strings based on whether they are indexed or not.

If you want to store more than 1500 bytes you should be able to - just make sure the field is defined in your schema as NOT indexed.

If you run into any problems, you can raise an issue here:

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/issues

P.S. the link you posted was to the Python-specific docs, which can be misleading as there are subtle differences.

Tom (php-gds author - thanks for the Kind words!:)

Comment: Thanks Tom! I had tried removing the index property (and deleting all existing rows in the datastore) but I still received the 1500 bytes error. I'm investigating the use of the blob type thats provided in the Google AppEngine PHP APIs, but am coming across issues documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313381/appengine-php-read-andwrite-string-to-blob

Comment: Let me run a test on strings and I'll get back to you. The Blob type is NOT supported yet by php-gds

Comment: Thanks Tom for all your work on this! I'm attempting to hack at your source  code to get the Blob type to work - I'll let you know if I get a working solution.

Comment: I've just tested strings of over 4,000 characters without a problem. Here is a Gist https://gist.github.com/tomwalder/d0728aaa7453d13725fe

Comment: I did write the upgrade to support the blob type - but the JSON encoding of binary data caused a problem, so I have not merged it into release yet. I do think think you need it though  -see my Gist above. If you want tho post me your code, I can take a look?

Comment: Ah so it seems the issue was that I hadn't re-indexed the DataStore after changing the index property for 'content' to FALSE. Even though I *thought* all the rows had been deleted for some reason the index persisted. This is working now - would that explanation make sense?

Comment: Each and every record put into Datastore carries it's own index definition with it. This means you *can* have 2 records - and they can have totally different index definitions for the same fields. If you change your Schema, you often will need to re-index any existing data. Some notes here: https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds#re-indexing