# AppEngine PHP read and write blob to datastore

Tags: php, blob, google-api-php-client

The Google AppEngine PHP API provides a way to read and write to a blob.

```
  public function setBlobValue($blobValue)
  {
    $this->blobValue = $blobValue;
  }
  public function getBlobValue()
  {
    return $this->blobValue;
  }
```

However this doesn't seem to work when writing / reading an html string stored in a blob, e.g.

```
$string = "<div>Test</div>"
$obj->setBlobValue(base64_encode($string));
```

then after a query:

```
$string = base64_decode($obj->getBlobValue());
```

doesn't work - is there something I'm doing wrong here?

(note this would be used to store much larger strings than the example here)

Comment: I don't think that's part of Google App Engine SDK. Where did you see that function?

Comment: You work for Google? https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Datastore.php

Comment: Yes. Have you tried writing shorter strings without base64 encode/decode?

Comment: There is a character limit on indexed strings so the idea was to workaround  this by using blobs.